# Manually installing themes and changing settings

Tags: themes, ccsm, icon-themes

I have always wondered if installing themes and changing setting seen on CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) possible manually. If so how can I manually install and change a theme using a command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once downloaded and placed in the theme `.themes` folder, you can use the following command to install a theme from the command line:

Unity, GNOME 3 Shell/Classic, Cinnamon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Yourtheme"
```

MATE:

```
mateconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/mate/interface/gtk_theme "Yourtheme"
```

Gnome 2:

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme "Yourtheme"
```

<sub>[**Source**](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/06/change-theme-command-line-gnome.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**GUI Ways**

Install theme at [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html) and then change your theme using gnome tweak tool
or unity tweak tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]
*Gnome tweak tool screenshot*

**Terminal ways**

Using gsettings commands to change icons/theme/gtk

For GTK

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "yourtheme"
```

For Theme

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "yourtheme"
```

For icons

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'yourtheme'
```

Comment: see my edit @Vesnog